# How to make a TParallel.&For loop responsive and store values in a TList<T>?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parallel-processing, thread-safety

In Delphi 10.1 Berlin I would like to make a `TParallel.&For` loop responsive.

I have a parallel loop similar to the example in question [TParallel.For: Store values in a TList while they are calculated in a TParallel.For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532891/tparallel-for-store-values-in-a-tlist-while-they-are-calculated-in-a-tparallel) . The loop calculates values and stores these values in a `TList<Real>`.

I try to run the `TParallel.&For` in a separate thread with `TTask.Run` to make it responsive:

```
type
  TCalculationProject=class(TObject)
  private
    Task: ITask;
    ...
  public
    List: TList<Real>;
    ...
  end;

function TCalculationProject.CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
begin
  //a function which takes a lot of calculation time
  //however in this example we simulate the calculation time and
  //use a simple alogorithm to verify the list afterwards
  Sleep(30);
  Result:=10*AIndex;
end;

procedure TCalculationProject.CalculateList;
begin
  List.Clear;

  Task:=TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LoopResult: TParallel.TLoopResult;
      Res: Real;
      Lock: TCriticalSection;
    begin
      Lock:=TCriticalSection.Create;
      try
        LoopResult:=TParallel.&For(0, 1000-1,
          procedure(AIndex: Integer; LoopState: TParallel.TLoopState)
          begin
            Res:=CalculateListItem(AIndex);                              
            Lock.Enter;
            try
              List.Add(Res);
            finally
              Lock.Leave;
            end;
          end
        );
      finally
        Lock.Free;
      end;

      if LoopResult.Completed then
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            SortList;
            ShowList;
          end
        );
      end;
    end
  );
end;
```

The problem is that the list is incorrect on a random basis: there are duplicate values in the list. For example:

```
list item 0: 0
list item 1: 10
list item 2: 20
list item 3: 20 <- incorrect
list item 4: 20 <- incorrect
list item 5: 50
....
```

Instead of the `Lock.Enter`  `Lock.Leave` part I have also tried `Synchronize`

```
TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
  procedure
  begin
    List.Add(Res);
  end
);
```

or

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    List.Add(Res);
  end
);
```

and `Queue`

```
TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
  procedure
  begin
    List.Add(Res);
  end
);
```

or

```
TThread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    List.Add(Res);
  end
);
```

but the problem remains. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Res` is global in scope for the parallel threads. The value of `Res` is thus undefined at the time of putting it into your list.

Comment: Make `Res` a local variable in the parallel.for and it will work.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now with ´TCriticalSection´, ´Synchronize´ and ´Queue´. Which one of these techniques should I use? What are the advantages / disadvantages of ´TCriticalSection´ vs. ´Synchronize´ vs. ´Queue´?

Comment: @user3384674, I would use none of those. I would preallocate a TArray<Real> with 1000 items, and I would write directly to it in the loop. (vArray[AIndex] := Res). Having locks might slow thing so much that you lose all the benefits of going multithread in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All threads in the `Parallel.For` loop shares the `Res` variable. When a thread is about to store the `Res` value into the list, it could already have been altered by one or many threads. In other words, the value of `Res` is unpredictable at the time of putting it into the list.

Fix it by making `Res` local to each thread.

As for which method is the best, I suggest to make a performance comparison. And the suggestion by @Ken seems like a good idea to try as well. Avoiding locks is often a recipe for good performance.

Also, compare against a loop without threads as well.