# How to stop a running TTask thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parallel-processing, thread-safety, wait

In Delphi 10.1 Berlin I would like to add the possibility to stop the responsive TParallel.&For loop from my question [How to make a TParallel.&For loop responsive and store values in a TList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071313/how-to-make-a-tparallel-for-loop-responsive-and-store-values-in-a-tlistt) .

The loop calculates values and stores these values in a TList. It runs in a separate thread with TTask.Run to make it responsive:

```
type
  TCalculationProject=class(TObject)
  private
    Task: ITask;
    ...
  public
    List: TList<Real>;
    ...
  end;

procedure TCalculationProject.CancelButtonClicked;
begin
  if Assigned(Task) then
  begin
    Task.Cancel;
  end;
end;

function TCalculationProject.CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
begin
  //a function which takes a lot of calculation time
  //however in this example we simulate the calculation time and
  //use a simple alogorithm to verify the list afterwards
  Sleep(30);
  Result:=10*AIndex;
end;

procedure TCalculationProject.CalculateList;
begin
  List.Clear;

  if Assigned(Task) then
  begin
    Task.Cancel;
  end;

  Task:=TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LoopResult: TParallel.TLoopResult;
      Lock: TCriticalSection;
    begin
      Lock:=TCriticalSection.Create;
      try
        LoopResult:=TParallel.&For(0, 1000-1,
          procedure(AIndex: Integer; LoopState: TParallel.TLoopState)
          var
            Res: Real;
          begin

            if (Task.Status=TTaskStatus.Canceled) and not(LoopState.Stopped) then
            begin
              LoopState.Stop;
            end;
            if LoopState.Stopped then
            begin
              Exit;
            end;

            Res:=CalculateListItem(AIndex);
            Lock.Enter;
            try
              List.Add(Res);
            finally
              Lock.Leave;
            end;
          end
        );
      finally
        Lock.Free;
      end;

      if (Task.Status=TTaskStatus.Canceled) then
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            List.Clear;
          end
        );
      end
      else
      begin
        if LoopResult.Completed then
        begin
          TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
            procedure
            begin
              SortList;
              ShowList;
            end
          );
        end;
      end;
    end
  );
end;
```

The current running calculation Task should be stopped when

1. the calculation is restarted
2. the user click on a cancel button

I added

```
if Assigned(Task) then
begin
  Task.Cancel;
end;
```

at the beginning of `procedure TCalculationProject.CalculateList` and in `procedure TCalculationProject.CancelButtonClicked` which is called when the cancel button is clicked.

The loop is stopped with

```
if (Task.Status=TTaskStatus.Canceled) and not(LoopState.Stopped) then
begin
  LoopState.Stop;
end;
if LoopState.Stopped then
begin
  Exit;
end;
```

and the list is cleared with

```
if (Task.Status=TTaskStatus.Canceled) then
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
    procedure
    begin
      List.Clear;
    end
  );
end
```

This does not work when I restart the calculation. Then two calculation tasks are running. I tried to add a `Task.Wait` after `Task.Cancel` to wait for the task to be finished before we start the new calculation but without success.

What is the correct fully thread-safe way to implement such a cancel/stop function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `Wait` does not work, is a dead-lock. The `Synchronize` call and `Wait` effectively stops a running task from finishing.

If you change all the `Synchronize` calls to `Queue`, you will avoid the dead-lock. But calling `Task.Cancel` in conjunction with `Task.Wait` on a running task will throw an `EOperationCancelled` error, so there is no luck going there.

---

**Update:** This was reported as a bug and is still not fixed in Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11267

---

To solve this specific problem, you need to be notified when the `Task` has ended, either through completion, being canceled or stopped.

When a task is started, the UI should block any attempt to start a new calculation until the former is ready/canceled.

- First, when a calculation task is started, disable the button which starts a new calculation.
- Second, synchronize or queue a call to enable the button at the end of the task.

Now, there is a safe way to know when the task is completed/stopped or cancelled.
With that in place, remove the `if Assigned(Task) then Task.Cancel` statement in the `CalculateList`method.

---

If the `CalculateListItem` method is time consuming, consider to regularly check the cancel status flag in there as well.

---

An example:

```
type
  TCalculationProject = class(TObject)
  private
    Task: ITask;
  public
    List: TList<Real>;
    procedure CancelButtonClicked;
    function CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
    procedure CalculateList(NotifyCompleted: TNotifyEvent);
    Destructor Destroy; Override;    
  end;

procedure TCalculationProject.CancelButtonClicked;
begin
  if Assigned(Task) then
  begin
    Task.Cancel;
  end;
end;

destructor TCalculationProject.Destroy;
begin
   List.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TCalculationProject.CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
begin
  //a function which takes a lot of calculation time
  //however in this example we simulate the calculation time and
  //use a simple alogorithm to verify the list afterwards
  Sleep(30);
  Result:=10*AIndex;
end;

procedure TCalculationProject.CalculateList(NotifyCompleted: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  if not Assigned(List) then
    List := TList<Real>.Create;

  List.Clear;

  Task:= TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LoopResult : TParallel.TLoopResult;
      Lock : TCriticalSection;
    begin
      Lock:= TCriticalSection.Create;
      try
        LoopResult:= TParallel.&For(0, 1000-1,
          procedure(AIndex: Integer; LoopState: TParallel.TLoopState)
          var
            Res: Real;
          begin
            if (Task.Status=TTaskStatus.Canceled) and not(LoopState.Stopped) then
            begin
              LoopState.Stop;
            end;
            if LoopState.Stopped then
            begin
              Exit;
            end;

            Res:= CalculateListItem(AIndex);
            Lock.Enter;
            try
              List.Add(Res);
            finally
              Lock.Leave;
            end;
          end);
      finally
        Lock.Free;
      end;

      if (Task.Status = TTaskStatus.Canceled) then
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            List.Clear;
          end)
      else
      if LoopResult.Completed then
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
         procedure
         begin
           SortList;
           ShowList;
         end);
      // Notify the main thread that the task is ended
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,  // Or TThread.Queue
        procedure
        begin
          NotifyCompleted(Self);
        end);
    end
  );
end;
```

---

And the UI call:

```
procedure TMyForm.StartCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartCalc.Enabled := false;
  CalcObj.CalculateList(TaskCompleted);
end;

procedure TMyForm.TaskCompleted(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartCalc.Enabled := true;
end;
```

---

In a comment, it appears as the user would want to trigger a cancel and a new task in one operation without being blocked.

To solve that, set a flag to true, call cancel on the task. When the `TaskCompleted` event is called, check the flag and if set, start a new task. Use `TThread.Queue()` from the task to trigger the `TaskCompleted` event.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However this is not what I need.

Comment: There will be several different scenarios how the calculation is started. E.g. the calculation is linked to a trackbar: when the user changes the value of the trackbar the calculation starts. I have to add that before the "long" calculation shown here there is a "quick" calculation. So: user changes trackbar -> do "quick" calculation in main thread and show result -> start "long" calculation in background thread -> show the result except when user changes the trackbar again before the end of the "long" calculation - in this case stop the calculation and start again with the new trackbar value.

Comment: Well, that is not what was asked for. Anyway that is still a how to handle the GUI in the best way. If the long calculation is not ready, set a flag to start a new calculation when you get the calc ready notification (better use the Queue variant to send the notification from the task thread).

Comment: Let's forget about the UI for the moment. I would like to understand multithreading correctly. After cancelling the calculation how do I know when the everything is finished (see last paragraph in my question: "I tried to add a Task.Wait after Task.Cancel to wait for the task to be finished before we start the new calculation but without success.")

Comment: Just as I said in my answer, send a message, either with Synchronize or Queue. The PPL is brittle, badly documented. Clearly Cancel/Wait does not work in your implementation. You can call `Task.Status` if you like. If status is completed you are good to start a new task. If it is canceled, I can't see from docs what that means (if the flag is set or the task is done and all cancel operations are finished) , but you still have to handle that and possibly start the task at another time. This is why I recommend to do it the way I proposed.

Comment: @user3384674, my latest edit should take care of your different scenarios, and explain the multithreading concerns. `TTask` does not supply an event when a task has been ended, and waiting is no option since that will either cause a dead-lock or an exception.

Comment: You mentioned that the PPL is brittle. Would it be better to use an implementation with TThread instead of TTask?

Comment: Most PPL bugs have been taken care of during the last years. If it works for you, fine. Most people have been using the OmniThreadLibrary framework for similar tasks for years. It has a learning curve, but is very well documented with examples. If you like to learn and is willing to experiment, you can try. Also using a normal `TThread` is doable of course, but it is difficult to state what is better.

Comment: Very nice solution. I managed to get it up and running. It is possible to start, cancel and "stopstart" tasks. This example however reliably crashes, when the application is terminated before the task is finished. 
I haven't found a solution for this problem yet.

Comment: @LübbeOnken, the example here assumes that the task is completed/canceled when the class is destroyed. You will have to manage that by preventing the application/form to close before the notification that the task is completed/canceled.

Answer (score 2):

Cancel is broken in System.Threading. See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11267

The following works by using another mechanism for signalling to the threads to stop (StopRunning).  Notice the use of LoopState.Break and LoopState.ShouldExit. Notice also the use of Queue instead of Synchronize.  This allows us to wait for the task on the main thread without blocking.

To use the code you need a form with a ListBox1 and two buttons btnStart and btnCancel.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnStart: TButton;
    btnCancel: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  private
    Task: ITask;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    List: TList<Double>;
    StopRunning : Boolean;
    function CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
    procedure CalculateList;
    procedure ShowList;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.SyncObjs;

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
begin
  //a function which takes a lot of calculation time
  //however in this example we simulate the calculation time and
  //use a simple alogorithm to verify the list afterwards
  Sleep(30);
  Result:=10*AIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List := TList<Double>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowList;
Var
  R : Double;
begin
  for R in List do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(R.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.CalculateList;
Var
  R : Real;
begin
  List.Clear;

  if Assigned(Task) then
  begin
    Task.Cancel;
  end;

  StopRunning := False;
  Task:=TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LoopResult: TParallel.TLoopResult;
      Lock: TCriticalSection;
    begin
      Lock:=TCriticalSection.Create;
      try
        LoopResult:=TParallel.For(0, 1000-1,
          procedure(AIndex: Integer; LoopState: TParallel.TLoopState)
          var
            Res: Double;
          begin

            if StopRunning then begin
              LoopState.Break;
              Exit;
            end;

            if LoopState.ShouldExit then
              Exit;

            Res:=CalculateListItem(AIndex);
            Lock.Enter;
            try
              List.Add(Res);
            finally
              Lock.Leave;
            end;
          end
        );
      finally
        Lock.Free;
      end;

    if LoopResult.Completed then
        TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            List.Sort;
            ShowList;
          end
        )
    else
      TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
        procedure
        begin
          List.Clear;
          ListBox1.Items.Add('Cancelled')
        end
      );
  end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopRunning := True;
  Task.Wait;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Clear;
  CalculateList;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @pyscripters answer I tried to encapsulate the functionality in a class and call the functions of this class from the UI.

- Starting a task works
- Stopping+starting a task while another is running works
- Closing the form while a task is running works

The final hint was to add CheckSynchronize to the Shutdown method.

```
unit uCalculation2;

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Threading;

type
  TNotifyTaskEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AMessage: string) of object;

  TCalc2 = class
  private
    FTask             : ITask;
    FOnNotifyTaskEvent: TNotifyTaskEvent;
    FCancelTask       : Boolean;

    function CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
    procedure CalculateList;
    procedure DoNotify(AMessage: string);

  public
    List: TList<Double>;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Start;
    procedure Stop;

    property OnNotifyTaskEvent: TNotifyTaskEvent read FOnNotifyTaskEvent write FOnNotifyTaskEvent;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.SyncObjs;

constructor TCalc2.Create;
begin
  List := TList<Double>.Create;
end;

destructor TCalc2.Destroy;
begin
  FOnNotifyTaskEvent := Nil;
  Stop;
  CheckSynchronize;

  FTask := Nil;
  List.Free;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TCalc2.DoNotify(AMessage: string);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnNotifyTaskEvent) then
    begin
      if Assigned(FTask) then
        AMessage := Format('%4d: %-40s Entries=%3d', [FTask.Id, AMessage, List.Count])
      else
        AMessage := Format('%4d: %-40s Entries=%3d', [0, AMessage, List.Count]);
      FOnNotifyTaskEvent(Self, AMessage);
    end;
end;

function TCalc2.CalculateListItem(const AIndex: Integer): Real;
begin
  //a function which takes a lot of calculation time
  //however in this example we simulate the calculation time and
  //use a simple alogorithm to verify the list afterwards
  Sleep(30);
  Result := 10 * AIndex;
end;

procedure TCalc2.CalculateList;
begin
  List.Clear;

  if Assigned(FTask) then
    begin
      FTask.Cancel;
    end;

  FCancelTask := False;

  FTask := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LoopResult: TParallel.TLoopResult;
      Lock: TCriticalSection;
    begin
//      TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
//        procedure
//        begin
//          DoNotify('Started');
//        end
//        );

      Lock := TCriticalSection.Create;
      try
        LoopResult := TParallel.For(0, 500 - 1,
          procedure(AIndex: Integer; LoopState: TParallel.TLoopState)
          var
            Res: Double;
          begin

            if FCancelTask then
              begin
                LoopState.Break;
                Exit;
              end;

            if LoopState.ShouldExit then
              Exit;

            Res := CalculateListItem(AIndex);
            Lock.Enter;
            try
              List.Add(Res);
            finally
              Lock.Leave;
            end;
          end
          );
      finally
        Lock.Free;
      end;

      if LoopResult.Completed then
        TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            DoNotify('Completed');
          end
          )
      else
        TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            DoNotify('Canceled');
          end
          );
    end
    );
end;

procedure TCalc2.Start;
begin
  CalculateList;
end;

procedure TCalc2.Stop;
begin
  FCancelTask := True;
  if Assigned(FTask) then
    FTask.Wait;
end;

end.
```

The calls from the UI look like this:

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCalc2 := TCalc2.Create;
  FCalc2.OnNotifyTaskEvent := CalcCompleted;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCalc2.Free;
end;

procedure TForm5.btnCalcCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCalc2.Stop;
end;

procedure TForm5.btnCalcRunClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CalcRun;
end;

procedure TForm5.btnRunAnotherClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CalcRun;
end;

procedure TForm5.CalcCompleted(Sender: TObject; Status: string);
begin
  memStatus.Lines.Add(Status);
  btnCalcRun.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm5.CalcRun;
begin
  btnCalcRun.Enabled := false;
  memStatus.Lines.Add('Started');
  FCalc2.Stop;
  FCalc2.Start;
end;
```

Comment: I don't get an AV here but try adding a call to CheckSynchronize to FormDestroy:  procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCalc2.Shutdown;
  CheckSynchronize;
  FCalc2.Free;
end;

Comment: As it stands the problem might be that DoNotify is called after a TCalc2.Free due to TThread.Queue.

Comment: Thank you, @PyScripter. CheckSynchronize does the trick. No crashes on exit anymore. I have updated my post and the code examples above so that it works.